# Why i am getting this error while doing PCA :- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, machine-learning, smote

```py
import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np 

import seaborn as sns

wine=pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv')

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

wine_x=wine.iloc[:,0:-1]
wine_y=wine.iloc[:,-1]

smt=SMOTE()

x,y=smt.fit_resample(wine_x,wine_y)
```

In the last code where I am fitting it, I get this AttributeError.

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py:646, in _OpenBLASModule.get_version(self)
    643 get_config = getattr(self._dynlib, "openblas_get_config",
    644                      lambda: None)
    645 get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646 config = get_config().split()
    647 if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648     return config[1].decode("utf-8")

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How could I correct it?

Comment: Could you please add the full error message starting from the line in your code that raised an error?

Comment: Where exactly? Please post a [mre] - plus, there does not seem to be any PCA in your code!

Comment: Most likely a version error. Update threadpoolctl or any lib that is using it( eg. Seaborn).

Comment: need code which is https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to train a MiniBatchKMeans model. I solved it by changing the Python version from 3.9 to 3.8 or 3.7